# How to change build.rs behavior based on the current Cargo command?

Tags: build, rust, rust-cargo

My build.rs is complicated since I am using it to generate tests and run some other binaries before actually compiling my current project. These tests rely on auto-generated code from these other binaries. These binaries can change dynamically thus changing the auto-generated code files so I do not want to statically write these tests. However, this ends up taking an enormous amount of time.

This is no problem when I want to run `cargo test`, but when I'm running `cargo build && cargo run` or `cargo bench` which don't need these generated tests, the long build time caused by build.rs becomes extremely annoying.

Is there any way to specify that I only want build.rs to execute when using `cargo test`? Is there some way in build.rs to detect which Cargo command is being run?

Comment: FYI, `cargo build && cargo run` is redundant. `cargo run` will build as needed.